# OpenCV compiled with GPU support but still get 0 from gpu::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount();

Tags: opencv, cuda

I have followed this tutorial http://home.eps.hw.ac.uk/~cgb7/opencv/opencv_tutorial.pdf and many others. But I still can't get gpu to work with opencv, the gpu::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount(); function still returns 0.

Com configuration:

- Windows8 64bit
- visual studio 2010
- tried with both opencv 245 and 246
- CUDA 5 64bit (but cmake obtains the 32bit libs and dlls)

I have also checked to see that the gpu.dll is >1M. Any ideas what could be wrong?

- Could it be property sheet? in the property sheet provided in the tutorial above I have edited to ensure the right version of opencv and added additional dependencies as I noticed that some are missing(ie:gpu and 2 others).
- I'm using user variables for the environment. Don't think that should be an issue.
- All the commands for gpu auto completes via intellesense, which means the property sheet should be correct right? or could there be a problem with linkers =/. Ahhh really confused as to why it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure when you configure Cmake options for OpenCV, the `WITH_CUDA` option is checked. Here are 2 comprehensive guides on how to build and use OpenCV 2.4.6 in Visual Studio 2010.

[How to Build OpenCV 2.4.6 with GPU Module in Windows](http://www.programmerfish.com/how-to-build-opencv-2-4-6-with-gpu-module-in-windows/)

[Step By Step Guide On Running OpenCV in Microsoft Visual Studio](http://www.programmerfish.com/running-opencv-in-microsoft-visual-studio/)

Disclaimer: I wrote these guides.

Comment: Thank you very much will try this asap. Ya I did enable with_cuda =/ it is ticked. and since my gpu is 2.1 i changed the 1st value to 2.1(2.0) and the second value to 2.0. Thank You again will try this.

Comment: Hi, I'm done compiling the debug version and i noticed i have 4 failed builds.
Not sure if it will still work will try first
52>  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
52>
52>Build FAILED.
55>Time Elapsed 00:02:26.74
54>  Deleting file "opencv_perf_gpu.dir\Debug\opencv_perf_gpu.unsuccessfulbuild".
54>  Touching "opencv_perf_gpu.dir\Debug\opencv_perf_gpu.lastbuildstate".
54>
54>Build succeeded.
54>
54>Time Elapsed 00:02:26.75
58>Build FAILED.
60>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python27_d.lib'
60>
60>Build FAILED

Comment: Hi again, yes i can verify this works. Although i did somethings differently at the property sheet but its almost the same. One query though. in the bin folder i have exes,ilk,dll,pdb and in the lib i have exp,lib and 2 pdb. Does these extra files affect my build/compilation time for my projects? Should I remove them? Thanks again sgar91

Comment: @ice... No presence of extra files will not increase the compilation time. Yes, you can remove them.